# Spring servlet /main unavailable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I just upgraded my Spring webapp from Java 7 to Java 8 and embedded Jetty 7 to Jetty 9

When I start my webapp using [Eclipse Jetty Integration](http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/), the Webapp seems to start from the logs but however I get the following error on console:

```
    2016-11-07 23:35:51.638:INFO:/:main: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
07 Nov 2016 23:35:51,642 [main] XmlValidatorContext INFO  - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Nov 07 23:35:51 EST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
07 Nov 2016 23:35:52,473 [main] Version INFO  - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
2016-11-07 23:35:53.413:WARN:/:main: unavailable
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.init(WebSocketServerFactory.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet.init(WebSocketServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
2016-11-07 23:35:53.414:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4cc8eb05{/,file:///home/bgandhi/mc-git-repos/mc-upgrade/mc/src/lib/webui/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/bgandhi/mc-git-repos/mc-upgrade/mc/src/lib/webui/src/main/webapp}
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet.init(WebSocketServlet.java:142)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
```

Also, while at Server startup console shows bunch of following errors:

```
2016-11-07 23:35:42.999:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:qtp780237624-136: 
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/eclipse/jetty/annotations/AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:984)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-07 23:35:42.999:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:qtp780237624-136: Unexpected thread death: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2@4eb937d1 in qtp780237624{STARTED,1<=27<=200,i=12,q=0}
2016-11-07 23:35:43.006:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:qtp780237624-143: 
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/eclipse/jetty/annotations/AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:984)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ...
```

i.m not sure how the above errors are caused. For the second error, some post suggested I should update the asm.jar to 5.1. I have asm-5.1.7.jar and asm-commons-5.1.jar in my WebApp libraries. It would be great help if someone can provide some insights on the errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the eclipse jars from your `WEB-INF/lib`, they are not supposed to be there.

Comment: Hi @JoakimErdfelt, Thanks for the quick reply. I don't have any Jars in `WEB-INF/lib`. My project is a gradle one I have linked all the libraries via build.gradle in the project directory.

Comment: The error you are getting is because the eclipse jars are being loaded by your webapp's classloader and the server classloader, that typically happens when the eclipse-jetty jars are included in the webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory as well.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, thank you so much for the suggestion. There are no files in WEB-INF/lib directory. However, when I was starting the Jetty server, there were a couple of jetty jar files that were created in WEB-INF/lib directory. I removed the references and moved it to external directory. Now when I start the app server, there are no files in WEB-INF/lib directory. However still I'm getting the same error!
Do you suggest to look over the other configuration which might be leading to the error?

Comment: It turns out my embedded Jetty did not had JSP support configured correctly. It's changed from Jetty 7.5 to Jetty 9.3. I changed it using the documentation provided here: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java.
I'm able to start my webapp, However I'm getting '404' while accesing the JSP pages.Also, while starting the jetty, I see  /webapp:main: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath. Not sure if there is a configuration mistake.